# How to parse a string to get the country names?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse the items in base_builds to get only the country names, I have the current and expected output,any idea what am I missing?

```
import re
base_builds = ['Australia10U613','England21W724','Canada31X835','Italy43Y946']

for base_build in base_builds:
    data = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+[a-z0-9]',base_build).group()
    print (data)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
Australia1
England2
Canada3
Italy4
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
Australia
England
Canada
Italy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex explicitly searches for strings that end in either a lowercase letter or a number. What you return ends in a number.

Just don't search for things ending in a number. Modified regex would be:

```
r'[a-zA-Z]+[a-z]'
```

or I'm not even sure why it needs to specifically end in a lowercase letter.

```
r'[a-zA-Z]+'
```